# Specific regex issue requiring assistance

Tags: regex

Here i provide you with an example of a line from my log file:
[13/02/2013 16:53] [join] John_Doe has joined the server (40:12.34.56.78)

To explain it in English it is: [Date Time] [join] Firstname_Lastname has joined the server (UserID:IP Address)

I wish to extract a list of names and IP's in CSV format.

Do you know a regex expression to run on each line to achieve this?

In this case, it would reveal:   John_Doe,12.34.56.78

Comment: Can the name's contain spaces within them, ie, `John Michael_Doe`?

Comment: [What, exactly, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You should try researching regular expressions. This question reveals the fact that you haven't even tried to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn regular expressions:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

This site contains a good general tutorial and tons of info on different regex implementations.

---

If you do *not* want to learn regular expressions:

http://txt2re.com/

This site lets you build regular expressions by entering your example pattern and clicking on the parts you need.

---

The regex you've asked for is so simple that it really shouldn't be posted here, as it would not be useful for other users.

Comment: +1 for both `If you want to learn` and `If you do not want to learn` options. I've never seen such a democratic answer. :)

Comment: @Neolisk: thanks :) I am not a big fan of "programming by clicking", and a regex built this way may not be optimal. But it is ok for a tool which runs only once... or as a start for manual enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\[join\] ([\w]+_[\w]+) has joined the server \((?:[\d]+:)([\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+)\)
```